# Adding a data.frame to an existing list containing vectors

Tags: r

I have a list which contains some vectors. For example "myList" looks like this:

```
myList

$mean
[1] 2    3    4    5    6    7    8    9    0    10

$sd
[1] 3    5    3
```

I want to add a new data.frame "data" to this existing list such that "myList" has three elements: `myList$mean`, `myList$sd` and `myList$data`.

How can this be done?

Comment: Try `myList$data <- data`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try

```
myList$data <- df
```

where `df` is your data frame

Answer (score 2):

Try this example:

```
#existing list
myList <- list(mean=c(1:10),
               sd=c(11:15))

#new dataframe
df1 <- data.frame(x=1:10,
                  y=11:20)
#add dataframe
myList$df <- df1

#result
str(myList)

#output
# List of 3
# $ mean: int [1:10] 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10
# $ sd  : int [1:5] 11 12 13 14 15
# $ df  :'data.frame':  10 obs. of  2 variables:
#   ..$ x: int [1:10] 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10
# ..$ y: int [1:10] 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20
```